# select all rows in excel containing same value in certain column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Stack Overflow and VBA.
I try to write some little VBA-code to select all rows (from A to E) in Excel containing a certain number.

(Parts of) My code as far

```
Dim ploeg as range
Dim ploeg2 as range

For v = 1 To 100
If Cells(v, 6) = 1 Then 
Set ploeg = Range(Cells(v, 1), Cells(v, 5))
Set ploeg2 = Union(ploeg2, ploeg)
End if
Next v

Ploeg2.Select
```

But this doesn't work...

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are columns F values either 1 or blanks?

Comment: They have value 1.

Comment: I mean, some column F cells have value 1, and those are what you’re interested with. While what value are in  column F other cells  ?

Comment: I start with an excel where each row represents a client. I want to select all clients belonging to the same branch, where the branch is represented by a number. So column F has values from 1 to 30.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were very close:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ploeg As Range
    Dim ploeg2 As Range

    For v = 1 To 100
        If Cells(v, 6) = 1 Then
            Set ploeg = Range(Cells(v, 1), Cells(v, 5))
            If ploeg2 Is Nothing Then
                Set ploeg2 = ploeg
            Else
                Set ploeg2 = Union(ploeg2, ploeg)
            End If
        End If
    Next v
    ploeg2.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

You just need to create `ploeg2` before adding to it with `Union()`.